# Set App TimeZone using PInvoke .Net

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I have used PInvoke to change the TimeZone of my Clients System. Instead of that Iwould like to change TimeZone of my Application only. Is there a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply store the timezone information in memory?  You should be able to also serialize this data so that it is persisted between application executions.

This way, your application can exist in a timezone entirely of your choosing, independent of your machine's time (and location).

The [TimeZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone(VS.71).aspx) class should be a good starting point for what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  The time zone setting is system-wide.  .NET does not provide any way to change the local time zone on a per-application basis.